# Issue with the adapter and RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am making an app to upload photos and show them in a gallery.

When I run my app it doesn't load the photos from firebase database. It gives me the error:

`No adapter attached; skipping layout`

I tried many solutions but all failed.

This is the activity:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ImageAdapter mAdapter;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private List<Upload> mUploads;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_images);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    mUploads.add(upload);
                }

                mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this, mUploads);

                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the adapter:

```
package com.example.android.shoftoh1;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.shoftoh1.R;
import com.example.android.shoftoh1.Upload;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;


// Create the basic adapter extending from RecyclerView.Adapter
// Note that we specify the custom ViewHolder which gives us access to our views
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Upload> mUploads;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        mContext = context;
        mUploads = uploads;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
        public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item, parent, false);
            return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
            holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());

            Picasso.get()
                    .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(holder.imageView);


        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    // Provide a direct reference to each of the views within a data item
    // Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
    static class ImageViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        // Your holder should contain a member variable
        // for any view that will be set as you render a row
        TextView textViewName;
        ImageView imageView;

        // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row
        // and does the view lookups to find each subview
        ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
            // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
        }


        }
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on the first line of code in your `onDataChange` method and run the app in the debugger, does it ever reach that breakpoint?

Comment: Yes It reach it

Comment: Thanks for confirming. That means you can step throgh the code from there. Does your `mUploads` get populated with the right data if you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try making this ImageViewHolder public

```
    // Provide a direct reference to each of the views within a data item
    // Used to cache the views within the item layout for fast access
    public class ImageViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        // Your holder should contain a member variable
        // for any view that will be set as you render a row
        public TextView textViewName;
       public ImageView imageView;

        // We also create a constructor that accepts the entire item row
        // and does the view lookups to find each subview
       public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
            // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
        }


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try to:

1. Move the `adapter` from the Firebase function to the rows that
   define    the `Recycler View`
2. Then update the list containing the `data` from `Firebase` (this can be the same list)
3. Finally, update the `adapter` that was made.

Good luck,
Well done!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to attach the adapter with empty list then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on updating the list as :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_images);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
    // attach the adapter with the empty list
    mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this, mUploads);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

           //now that mUploads has been updated call notifyDataSetChanged(). 
           //Also, if you know the position that was inserted you can 
           //use other variant such as notifyItemInserted().
           mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```